# ORDER BY causing query not to work?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, advantage-database-server

I have a query that is working as intended in access. I have "converted" it for a web system which it does not want to work. The query however is working correctly when I remove the `ORDER BY` (At the very bottom of the example posted) which is required.

I am unsure what could be causing the problem. The error message which appears is the following:
`Expected lexical element not found: ) There was a problem parsing the table names after the FROM keyword in your SELECT statement. -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 812 (line: 17 column: 72)`

I don't want to post the whole query as it is long (Unless requested), but the problem occurs on the bottom line:

```
    SELECT TOP 5 [90Days].PRODUCT, [90Days].product2, [90Days].pcustkey, [90Days].[90DayThroughput], TABLETHREE.SumOfLQUAN AS [Current Stock], (ROUND([SumOfLQUAN]/[90DayThroughput],3))*90 AS [DaysRemaining] FROM
    (
        SELECT TABLEONE.PRODUCT, Sum(TABLEONE.QUANTITY) AS [90DayThroughput], TABLETWO.product2, TABLETWO.pcustkey FROM TABLETWO INNER JOIN TABLEONE ON TABLETWO.PRODCODE = TABLEONE.PRODUCT WHERE
        (
            (
                (TABLEONE.DATE)>='$date'-90
            )
            AND
            (
                (TABLEONE.type)='I11' Or (TABLEONE.type)=' 11'
            )
            AND
            (
                (TABLETWO.POWNER)='$custCode'
            )
        )
        GROUP BY TABLEONE.PRODUCT, TABLETWO.product2, TABLETWO.pcustkey ORDER BY Sum(TABLEONE.QUANTITY) DESC
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can provide more of the query if required.

Comment: Perhaps you should be saying `ORDER BY [90DayThroughput]`? Dunno ...

Comment: If you are using Codeigniter, I would recommend you use Active Record Database Pattern on your queries. Its simpler.

Comment: @MikeRobinson This results in the exact same problem :( thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: @JobSam I will look into this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some of the query if it was working before adding the Order by
there is no join to TABLETHREE

Ive created the following so i could run the query

```
TRY
DROP TABLE #Table1;
CATCH ADS_SCRIPT_EXCEPTION
IF __errcode = 7112 THEN
--Do Nothing
ELSE
RAISE; // re-raise the exception
END IF;
END TRY;

TRY
DROP TABLE #Table2;
CATCH ADS_SCRIPT_EXCEPTION
IF __errcode = 7112 THEN
--Do Nothing
ELSE
RAISE; // re-raise the exception
END IF;
END TRY;

Select 'AAA' as Product, 12 as Quantity, 'I11' as Type, curdate() as  "Date"
into #Table1
from System.iota;

Select 'AAA' as Product, 'AAA111' as CustKey, '$custCode' as POwner, 'MyPRODCODE' as PRODCODE, 'KEY' as pcustkey
into #Table2
from System.iota;
```

i have commented out the TABLETHREE stuff
you needed to have a )"90Days" after your group by
and iv'e changed the order by ORDER BY [90Days].[90DayThroughput] DESC

```
SELECT TOP 5 
[90Days].PRODUCT, 
[90Days].product2, 
[90Days].pcustkey, 
[90Days].[90DayThroughput] 
--,#Table3.SumOfLQUAN AS [Current Stock], 
--(ROUND([SumOfLQUAN]/[90DayThroughput],3))*90 AS [DaysRemaining] 
FROM
    (
        SELECT tb1.PRODUCT, 
        Sum(tb1.QUANTITY) AS [90DayThroughput], 
        tb2.PRODCODE as product2, 
        tb2.pcustkey 
        FROM #Table2 tb2
        INNER JOIN #Table1 tb1 ON tb2.PRODCODE = tb1.PRODUCT WHERE
        (
            (
                (tb1.DATE)>=curdate()-90
            )
            AND
            (
                (tb1.type)='I11' Or (tb1.type)=' 11'
            )
            AND
            (
                (tb2.POWNER)='$custCode'
            )
        )
        GROUP BY tb1.PRODUCT, tb2.PRODCODE, tb2.pcustkey 
    )"90Days"
ORDER BY [90Days].[90DayThroughput] DESC
```